libxml2 not pretty print if xml contains whitespaces?
I have the following sample XML. if I feed it to libxml2 without any formatting or whitespace in between, then it would pretty-print fine when calling xmlNodeDump() with 1:
const char *xml= "<root><a>test</a></root>";

However, if I preformat it, or have spaces in between, then libxml2 refuses to pretty-print it, for example:
const char *xml =
"<root>"
"  <a>"
"    test"
"  </a>"
"</root>";

Then I call the function to read it like this:
#define MY_PARSER_OPTIONS (XML_PARSE_RECOVER | XML_PARSE_NOENT | XML_PARSE_DTDLOAD | XML_PARSE_DTDATTR | XML_PARSE_HUGE)
...

doc = xmlReadDoc((const xmlChar *) xml, NULL, NULL, MY_PARSER_OPTIONS);
...
xmlNodePtr root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
xmlBufferPtr buf = xmlBufferCreate();
xmlNodeDump(buf, doc, root, 0, 1);

The output would not be formatted.
When the input contains spaces, the output is:
<root>  <a>    test  </a></root>

When the input contains no spaces, the output is:
<root>
  <a>test</a>
</root>

Is this a bug in libxml2? How can I have it pretty-print/format correctly? There is no error from either of the input.
UPDATE:
With minimal reproducible example:
https://github.com/totszwai/libxml2-troubleshoot1
As we can see, when the input contains some spacing, libxml2 cannot format it, for some reason.


Also, pleas avoid code breakage with ellipses, post a [mre] - compliable and with main()

@3CxEZiVlQ from the examples output, you can see that there is zero indentation, xmlNodeDump just dumps the whole thing in a straight line without any expected linebreak...

@3CxEZiVlQ Fixed the typos

Seems to me that libxml is treating the spaces in your 'with spaces' input as signifcant somehow and therefore not destroying it by reformatting the input.

@3CxEZiVlQ added reproducible example

Try including the XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS option when calling xmlReadDoc(). Per the libxml2 documentation:

Remove some text nodes containing only whitespace from the result document. Which nodes are removed depends on DTD element declarations or a conservative heuristic. The reindenting feature of the serialization code relies on this option to be set when parsing.


You are right, the weird spacing is because libxml2 was treading all the characters including the whitespace within <a></a> as the text value "    test  " whereas when I put additional children node within <a> then it would correctly format it. Thanks

"the whitespace within <a></a> as the text value " test "" - that is correct behavior for that example, as that whitespace is significant as part of <a>'s text and can't be ignored. But the whitespace between the opening <root> and <a> tags is insignificant and can be ignored.

I want to point out that while using XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS does fix this particular concern, you need to be careful when using it to read the incoming XML, if you are doing digital signature validation, using NOBLANKS could cause the digital signature validation to fail as the original signed content could be different without the blanks/whitespaces. So, now I only use NOBLANKS when constructing a brand new XML document.
